# Changing the color and font size of button titles in swift(for osx NOT ios)

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swift2

I want to change the color of one of my button titles. First I tried some simple guesses:

```
Button.title.textColor = NSColor(/*something*/)
Button.Color = NSColor( /*something*/ )
Button.textColor = NSColor( /*something*/ )
```

But they didn't work. Then I found the following code on the internet:

```
Button.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: /*something*/ , attributes: /*something*/ [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : NSColor( /*something*/ ), NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : NSMutableParagraphStyle() ])
```

But it's long and complicated and can't change the color without assigning additional characteristics(other than leaving them to the default values set in the interface builder); also, most importantly, when I use it, it changes the font size to a small font size(ignoring the font size I set in the interface builder) and I don't know how to change it back again.
Is there any better code that I can use? If not how can I assign a value for the font size in the code above?

Comment: I just did that a little while ago. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31088172/how-to-set-the-title-text-color-of-uibutton and also this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36831596/ios-button-title-color-wont-change

Comment: @Katherine Jenkins those posts are for iOS not osx. I tried the codes but they didn't work

Comment: Apologies. Completely missed that. My colleague asked me to refer you to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28608727/change-color-to-a-title-of-a-button-in-swift ... hope that link is more helpful ;)

Comment: I already knew that (as I wrote in my question). My problem is that when I use it, it changes the font size to a smaller font size and I don't know how to change it back

Comment: Why is the question down voted? It's a clear enough question: How can I have a custom color and font size for a button title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an attributed string which includes both color and font size (more information:  [How do I make an attributed string using Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24666515/how-do-i-make-an-attributed-string-using-swift)
)
And then use

```
button.attributedTitle
```

to set the title

Answer (score 2):

if you want change color of button title. use this.

// redColor() just use as a example.

```
Button.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Comment: That's for Ios . I'm programming for osx

Answer (score 0):

NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSColor (/**something*/) forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];

NSAttributedString *attr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Text" attributes:dict];

[Button setAttributedTitle:attr];

Comment: When I use it, it changes the font size and I don't know how to change it back. It's the problem I mentioned in the question

Comment: You can add the font size also to the attribute dictionary:

[NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,[NSFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:5.0f],NSFontAttributeName, nil];

Comment: You can get the font size which you have set in interface builder using the following code:
    float size = Button.font.pointSize;